# How to change column values or create values in a new column based on values in existing column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to ML and Data Science (recently graduated from Master's in Business Analytics) and learning as much as I can by myself now while looking for positions in Data Science / Business Analytics.

I am working on my personal project to build ML algorithms to predict if a customer will show up to their existing appointment.

Upon initial data analysis, I notice that my "No-show" column contains values "Yes" and "No" (Metadata: if a customer scheduled an appointment and showed up for an appointment, the value in "No-show" column is "No"; if a customer scheduled an appointment and did not show up for an appointment, "No-show" column value is "Yes"). For ML algorithms, I need values "Yes" to become "1", and values "No" become "0".

I realize that there are 2 ways to tackle this problem:

1. write a code to change values of "No-show" column
2. create a new "Outcome" column whose values will depend on values in "No-show"

I tried writing code for both cases, but I continue to get different errors. Below are the 2 methods I attempted, and neither work. I appreciate your help in advance!

**1.**

```
if my_df["No-show"] == "Yes":
    my_df["No-show"] == 1
elif my_df["Outcome"] == "No":
    my_df["No-show"] == 0
else:
    print("Something went wrong")

Error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

**2.1**

```
my_df["Outcome"] = 0

if my_df["No-show"] == "Yes":
    my_df["Outcome"] == 1
elif my_df["No-show"] == "No":
    my_df["Outcome"] == 0
else:
    print("Something went wrong")

Error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

**2.2**

```
my_df["Outcome"] = 0

for val in my_df.iterrows():
    if my_df["No-show"] == "Yes":
        my_df["Outcome"] == 1
    elif my_df["No-show"] == "No":
        my_df["Outcome"] == 0
    else:
        print("Something went wrong")

Error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Thank you for your help, and congratulate me on my first question on StackOverflow! Looking forward to give back to community! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: Have you looked at the [Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/)?

Comment: @Arsik36 One issue is that you aren't using `val` in the for loop.  Also, there's a more succinct way to do it: `my_df['Outcome'] = (my_df['No-show'] == 'Yes').astype(int)`

Comment: As an aside, having a variable `"No-show"` is going to get confusing. Also, why use 0/1 instead of actual bools?

Comment: @Chris Thank you, this helped! One beginner-style question; how does Python now to translate "Yes" value to 1 in a new column, since you didn't explicitly specify that in your code? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @AMC thank you for your feedback. This is exactly why I am creating a new "Outcome" column to avoid having weird signs in column names

Comment: `my_df['No-show'] == 'Yes'` will return a `pandas.Series` of the same length (number of rows) as `my_df`, with `True` or `False` for each row depending on whether the `No-show` column matches the given string (`'Yes'` in this case).  Using the `astype()` method converts those boolean values to integers (`True` becomes `1` and `False` becomes `0`).  This is assigned via the usual `=` operator to `my_df['Outcome']`, which creates the new column in the dataframe.  As @AMC suggested, you will do well to read the pandas documentation – it's really clear and concise.

Comment: @Chris thank you, I appreciate your help!